# Retornar valor adentro de un onResponse

Tags: java, android-studio, api, variables, android-volley

Estoy usando la librería Volley y mi objetivo en este caso es devolver una variable en especifico que esta adentro de mi **OnResponse**, para luego poder manipularla en otros métodos, la variable tiene el nombre de: "**theFlag**". Existe alguna forma de retornarla sin perder el valor?

```
private void getMyFlag(String nombre) {
        String URL = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        String theFlag;
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for(int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                if(nombre.equals(jsonObject.getString("country"))){
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("countryInfo");
                                    theFlag = jsonObject1.getString("flag"); //variable que quiero retornar
                                    
                                }



                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que deseas almacenar la variable que retorna para luego poder usarla en otros métodos.
Lo que haría es crear una variable por ejemplo:`String the_flag= ""`, esta estaría declarada arriba de onCreate.
Luego la almacenas como: `the_flag = jsonObject1.getString("state");`. De ese modo ya la podrías llamar en cualquier momento.

Ahora si lo que quieres hacer es manipularla por cualquier actividad o fragmento, lo que yo haría es usar **SharedPreferences** para almacenar, claramente se tendrá que ejecutar primero el código para la recolección del dato.